# How to duplicate a camera?

Tags: camera

Is it possible to duplicate a camera in a scene? I tried selecting the camera an going to Object >> Duplicate Objects but it doesn't seem to duplicate the selected camera.

Comment: I also found out I had the camera hidden I was trying to duplicate. xD If anyone else has that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is definitely possible.
You even did it already ;) Just: the new camera has got exactly the same settings as the original. Means: In the 3D view both lay exactly over each other and appear as one.

Press "G" for grabbing and move mouse for moving the new (selected) camera after duplicating. Once you reached the wanted position, press the left mouse button.

Alternatively you can use the short cut "Shift + D" for duplicating and grabbing the camera. Now you're able to reposition the camera after duplicating it.

Greets
Jaspa